# How do I put a "#" into a token list without getting two?

Tags: tex-core

Consider this plain TeX file:

```
\newtoks\t
\t={#}
\showthe\t
\bye
```

If you compile it (with `tex` of `pdftex`), then in the output you get

```
> ##.
l.3 \showthe\t
```

Why do I get *two* of the `#`s?

(The background: I want to build the body of a macro definition in a token list, and the macro takes one argument that I want to put into the token list as `#1`. The idea is to use `\edef\macro#1{\the\t}`.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When TeX *shows* `#`, it doubles it up. So in your

```
\newtoks\t
\t={#}
\showthe\t
\bye
```

example,

```
> ##.
l.3 \showthe\t
```

represents *one* `#` inside the token register. You can convince TeX to show this using `\string`:

```
\newtoks\t
\t={#}
\expandafter\string\the\t
\bye
```

(which of course only works because there is a single token in `\t`!)

For the definition of the macro, you'd need something like

```
\newtoks\t
\t={You gave '#1'}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\test
  \expandafter#\expandafter1\expandafter{\the\t}
\test{things}
\bye
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `\detokenize{#}` gives two `##`. Is that a bug in pdfTeX?

Comment: @TH. No, not a bug. `\detokenize` is meant to work very much like a toks, in the sense that you could do the same as `\detokenize` achieves by writing a toks to file and reading back with appropriate catcode changes. However, `\detokenize` is expandable whereas working _via_ a file is not. If you try the file-based route, you'll also get two `#`.

Comment: Yeah. I was actually hoping to use `\detokenize` to write a single `#` to the file which is where I ran across it. I forget the exact reason now. Still, I'd assume that a `#_6` token would be replaced by a single `#_12` token. E.g., I'd expect `\scantokens\expandafter{\detokenize{\def\foo#1{#1}}}` to work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about `\show`. But why doesn't `\edef\macro#1{\the\t}` work? (I knew about the `\expandafter` workaround, but it's nasty, and I'm puzzled why this _does_ work then.)

Answer (score 3):

Joseph answered the reason why # shows up double, as the standard behaviour of show etc.

Since you  want to build the body of a macro definition in a token list the only way to incorporate #1 etc. (IMHO) is to put the to put it via a macro.

```
\newtoks\t
\t={\def\z#1{\bf #1}}
\def\macro#1{\the\t \z{B} \z{#1}}
\macro{test}

\bye
```

The only difference from what was proposed by the OP, is that to put the body definition in a token list, you need to pass it to the macro by using `\the\t` and a `\helpermacro{#1}`.

Answer (score 3):

Following what Yiannis wrote, you can do something like this:

```
% Put the replacement text into \t, using any computation like this doubling loop
\newtoks\t
\t{#1}
\count255 0
\loop\ifnum\count255<10
        \t\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\the\expandafter\t\the\t}
        \advance\count255 1
\repeat
% Define a helper that when executed will perform the real definition
\edef\helper{\noexpand\def\noexpand\X##1{\the\t}}
\helper
% Now the real macro \X can be used.
\X{[X] }
\bye
```

Comment: @TH.: That looks a bit clearer than the 5 `\expandafter` s in Joseph's suggestion, but I'm still puzzled why a simple `\edef\macro#1{\the\t}` doesn't work. (Fortunately, the initial reason for this post has gone since my `\multexpafter` got a lot simpler now.)

Comment: @Hendrik This is designed as such in TeX. Tokens resulting from `\the\token` variable are not expanded further if the statement occurs inside an `\edef` macro definition.

Comment: @Yiannis: That's not the issue. The issue is that `\t{#1}\edef\macro#1{\the\t}` is the same as `\def\macro#1{##1}` which doesn't work: `! You can't use 'macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.` By stuffing it inside another macro, (`\helper` in my code) causes it to work.

Comment: @TH.: Can you explain _why_ `\t{#1}\edef\macro#1{\the\t}` is the same as `\def\macro#1{##1}`? I can't find this described in the TeXbook.

Comment: @Hendrik: No. I cannot explain why that is the case. I can merely demonstrate that it is: `\newtoks\t \t{#1} \edef\macro#1{\the\t} \show\macro \def\macro#1{##1} \show\macro \end`. Best guess is it's a bug in TeX. I can't think of a reason that `\ea\def\ea\macro\ea#\ea1\ea{\the\t}` should behave differently from the `\edef` version.

Comment: @TH.: Thanks for telling me that I'm not alone. However, I don't think it's a bug (although it looks like one): There's one cryptic indication in the TeXbook that it is "status-bydesign", namely on p.216, 6th double-dangerous-bend-paragraph. Maybe you can make something out of what's written there?

Comment: @Hendrik: I don't think that applies here. It's saying that TeX automatically doubles the `#` there. E.g., `\immediate\write-1{\def\noexpand\foo#1{#1}}` writes `\def \foo ##1{##1}` to the log. Inside an `\edef`, you'd write `\edef\bar{\def\noexpand\foo##1{##1}}`.

Comment: @TH.: Thanks, it seems that I totally misread that paragraph. The mystery remains ... probably one has to have a look at tex.web.

Comment: @Hendrik: what, you don't have Volume B ;-)?

Comment: @SamB: Finally (after your recent question) I understand what you're talking about. I thought it was a joke and that you mean a Volume B of the TeXbook. No, I've never seen a copy of "TeX: The Program".

Comment: @TH. @Hendrik: `\ea\def\ea\macro\ea#\ea1\ea{\the\t}` expands `\the\t` before knowing that we are inside a definition. `\edef#1{\the\t}` expands `\the\t` while knowing that we are inside a definition, so it doubles hashes.

Comment: @Bruno: That makes sense, but is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @Bruno: Great, thanks. I'd also like to know where this is documented, but the mystery starts unraveling. (One of the mysteries of comment-@-replies unraveled: Only the _first_ user is notified. So if you had written "@Hendrik @TH:", then both TH and I would have gotten a notification; TH as the poster of the answer, and I due to the "@Hendrik".)

Comment: @Hendrik, @TH.: I have no idea if this is documented. I just thought about the explanation this morning after reading that post a few days ago. --- Also, thanks for the @-tip. Would `\catcode\`\@=\active\def@#1: {\notify{#1}}@Hendrik: @TH.: ` work?