# How can I provide a verbatim (unescaped) commandline for executing with \write18?

Tags: verbatim, shell-escape

When using `\write18` to execute shell commands, there are some cases where lots of backslash strings, and other 'special' LaTeX characters are required in the commandline to be executed (e.g. if a regular-expression is needed, or when using awk).

It would be convenient to have a way of typing the command exactly as it should appear when used on the commandline (i.e. without needing to use `\string`, etc.), and having it parsed verbatim, and given as an argument to `\write18`.  What ways are there of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try

```
\write18{\unexpanded{...}}
```

In order to avoid doubled `#` marks and to use `%`, you can define

```
\def\exec{\begingroup\setexeccatcodes\innerexec}
\def\setexeccatcodes{\catcode`\#=12 \catcode`\%=12 }
\def\innerexec#1{\immediate\write18{\unexpanded{#1}}\endgroup}
```

However you can't use `\exec` in the argument of another command, because this freezes category codes. Should you need it, one has to work also with `\scantokens`. Braces must be balanced, but this should not be a problem.

Another possibility, suggested by Martin Scharrer, is to use `\detokenize`:

```
\def\exec#1{\immediate\write18{\detokenize{#1}}}
```

which however might insert unwanted spaces in case backslashes are used in the argument. The advantage is that this macro can be used in arguments to other commands.

Comment: Nice -- I wasn't aware of `\unexpanded`.  By the way, the # -> ## problem (mentioned in Hendrik's comment below) still exists with `\unexpanded`.  I guess one could write a `\execunexpanded` macro which handles this?

Comment: One other thing `\unexpanded` seems not to handle well is `%`.  I guess one would need to do something similar with catcodes?

Comment: Using `\write18{\detokenize{...}}` would also be a possibility, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Martin I guess so.

Comment: Is there a `\percentchar`-like macro but for `$`?

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ Just add ``\catcode`$=12``

Comment: +1 for the `\unexpanded` it just worked to preserve the tilde in my path `~/temp/myfile.log`. Yeah! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

egreg has an answered for the typical case where e-TeX is available. In the original TeX-82 program you'd do effectively the same using a token register

```
\newtoks\mytoks
\mytoks{<commands-go-here>}
\immediate\write18{\the\mytoks}
```

(This works because token registers are only expanded once in `\write` contexts, in analogy to their behaviour inside `\edef`. The `\unexpanded` solution effectively does the same thing without needing the assignment operation.)

Comment: This has the drawback that a `#` would be doubled ([which has already confused me a lot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8200/how-do-i-put-a-into-a-token-list-without-getting-two)).

Comment: @Hendrik: If you need to echo `#` in this context I'd change the catcode temporarily. (Getting single `#` tokens is a pain, as you know.)

Comment: @Hendrik: a crazier alternative to changing the catcode of `#` locally is to globally do `\let\macparchar#\catcode\`\#=13\let#\macparchar`. Then `#`, albeit active, will work as usual, and to disable its doubling you can just `\let#\relax` (then that works in the argument of a command).

Answer (score 9):

With `xparse`'s verbatim argument type introduced a couple of months ago, this is quite easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\commandline}{v}
  { \immediate \write 18 { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\commandline|echo "Hello World! @#$%^"|

\stop
```

Answer (score 7):

The 2011/07/23 version of my `newverbs` package now provides `\Verbdef` which can be used to define verbatim material into macros using a `\write`-able form (I call it *plain verbatim*). The `verbdef` package provides `\verbdef` which defines macros with additional font related code to *typeset* the material which makes it unsuitable for `\write`.

```
\usepackage{newverbs}[2011/07/23]

\Verbdef\myhash{#}
\Verbdef\mypercent{%}

\immediate\write18{foo \myhash bar \mypercent bar }

\Verbdef\mycommand|perl dosomething.sh '4%^*&_{#'|
\immediate\write18{\mycommand}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `bashful` package:

```
\bash
echo "\documentclass{Article}\begin{document}Hello, World!\end{document}" > try.tex
latex try.tex
\END
```

should work as expected, i.e., generate a latex file from within latex, and then submitting it to processing by latex.