# How can I write % into a file?

Tags: verbatim, auxiliary-files, write-file

How can I write `%` into an auxiliary file? `%` will not work, because LaTeX thinks that I start a comment with it (in the main file, not in the auxiliary file!), and `\%` will write `\%` into the file. How can it be accomplished?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\outfile
\immediate\openout\outfile=example.dat
\immediate\write\outfile{%}% will not work, of course, but neither \%
\immediate\closeout\outfile
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer to [How can I provide a verbatim (unescaped) commandline for executing with \write18?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14186/how-can-i-provide-a-verbatim-unescaped-commandline-for-executing-with-write18/24281#24281) which should also answer this question.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Please see additional answer. You could have posted that as answer yourself. +1 to your comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is `\@percentchar` that expands to a literal `%` character. You need to enclose your writing operation in a `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` pair

```
\makeatletter
\newwrite\outfile
\immediate\openout\outfile=example.dat
\immediate\write\outfile{\@percentchar}
\immediate\closeout\outfile
\makeatother
```

An alternative with escaping the `%` inspired by an example where

```bsh
git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h-%ad" --date=short > /tmp/temp.dat
```

needs to be passed to `\write18`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\dosystem{%
  \@ifstar{\@tempswafalse\do@system}{\@tempswatrue\do@system}%
}
\newcommand\do@system[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\%\@percentchar
  \if@tempswa\expandafter\immediate\fi
  \write18{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

so the command above can be executed by saying

```
\dosystem{git log -1 --pretty=format:"\%h-\%ad" --date=short > /tmp/temp.dat }
```

With `\dosystem*` the `\write` is delayed at the next shipout (because `\immediate` is not executed).

Other characters can be escaped using the same idea, adding other `\let` instructions. If also braces and `#` are needed, an extended definition would be

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\dosystem{%
  \@ifstar{\@tempswafalse\do@system}{\@tempswatrue\do@system}%
}
\edef\@hashmark{\string#}\edef\@lbrace{\string{}\edef\@rbrace{\string}}
\newcommand\do@system[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\%\@percentchar
  \let\#\@hashmark
  \let\{\@lbrace
  \let\}\@rbrace
  \if@tempswa\expandafter\immediate\fi
  \write18{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

and in the argument also `\#`, `\{` and `\}` can be used for escaping those characters.

Comment: It is worth noting that expl3 provides the constant string `\c_percent_str`.

Answer (score 5):

use `\@percentchar` or `\charxxx`  where xxx is the decimal number of %

Comment: `\symbol{37}` won't write `%`, but rather `\char37`.

Comment: Also `\char` is unexpandable

Comment: And being unexpandable I can't use it.

Answer (score 5):

As other answers note, you need one way or another to output the string `%`.  For users not using LaTeX, something like

```
\def\percentchar#1{}
\edef\percentchar{\expandafter\percentchar\string\%}
```

will generate a macro `\percentchar` which can be used for this purpose. (I've used `\percentchar` twice rather than define a 'gobble' command: just to avoid 'name waste'. Many people will have something of that sort set up anyway.) Thus for example with the above

```
\immediate\write-1{\percentchar}
```

will write `%` to the log file.

Another alternative is to alter the category code of `%`

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`\%=12
  \immediate\write-1{%}\relax
\endgroup
```

although this does require a bit more care terminating lines correctly (for example, the `\relax` above is needed if we cannot assume vertical mode).

Answer (score 4):

Following the comment of Martin Scharrer I read up on his [newverbs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newverbs) package.
With this the following is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newverbs}
\Verbdef\verbpercent{%}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\outfile
\immediate\openout\outfile=example.dat
\immediate\write\outfile{\verbpercent}
\immediate\closeout\outfile
\end{document}
```

Comparison with the use of `\@percentchar`:

- Advantage: `\Verbdef` can generally be used for any verbatim text,
  and doesn't require `\makeatletter \makeatother`.
- Disadvantage: It uses more of TeX's memory and more time to compile
  (both: slightly), and theoretically there could be an incompatibility
  between package newverbs and some other package.

(Therefore I use `\@percentchar`, but reference to the `newverbs` package surely is useful for the general case.)

As [user202729](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/250119/user202729) pointed out in a comment at May 20th, 2023, in sufficiently new LaTeX versions this solution breaks: [How do I write the hashtag symbol # into an output file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591481/how-do-i-write-the-hashtag-symbol-into-an-output-file). Since 2018/12/01 LaTeX provides the command `\protected@file@percent`. If example.dat is not further processed with LaTeX but needs an actual "%", then this would not help.

Comment: In sufficiently new version this solution breaks: [How do I write the hashtag symbol # into an output file? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591481/how-do-i-write-the-hashtag-symbol-into-an-output-file)i