# \immediate\write18 cannot handle %?

Tags: shell-escape

I would like to do something like this:

```
\immediate\write18{git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h-%ad" --date=short > /tmp/temp.dat }
```

however, xelatex cannot proceed because the % means comment out
if I do this:

```
\immediate\write18{git log -1 --pretty=format:"\%h-\%ad" --date=short > /tmp/temp.dat }
```

The call is actually:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:"\%h-\%ad" --date=short > /tmp/temp.dat
```

which will have extra `\` in it.

How can I let the shell command use `%` instead of `\%` ?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34390/how-can-i-write-into-a-file for example

Comment: it did not work, I think it is only for writing stuff not shell escape? I got `\spacefactor \@m {}percentchar h;\spacefactor \@m {}percentchar ad`

Comment: You need `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` around code using `\@percentchar`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: thanks, I am using ``\catcode`\%=11`` ``\catcode`\%=14`` pair now.