# How to escape double quotes in \input

Tags: input, shell-escape, unix

I'm trying to call shell commands that contain multiple (nested)
quotation marks. This is, for instance, what I would write on the shell:

```
$ python -c "print \"Hello World\""
```

which produces `Hello World`. I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16790)
that `\input` can read from the standard output when started with a `|`.
However, it is not surprising that the following produces not what I want:

```
\input{|"python -c "print \"Hello World\"""}
```

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75680), the following works fine:

```
\immediate\write18{python -c "print \string\"Hello World\string\"" > \jobname.pyout}
\input{\jobname.pyout}
```

but requires a temporary file. Also, using `\detokenize` seems to work with `\write18`:

```
\immediate\write18{\detokenize{python -c "print \"Hello World\""} > \jobname.pyout}
\input{\jobname.pyout}
```

Is there a solution that doesn't need to write a file?

Comment: There is a python package that enables one to use python in TeX. Perhaps it's what you want to achieve?

Comment: maybe `luatex`  is an option for you. Instead of using `python` you can use `lua` and pass the output directly into the TeX document: `\directlua{tex.print("Hello Pi: "..math.pi)}`

Comment: I look rather for a minimal solution. Ultimately, I want to call this from within tikz figures and use it with tikz's externalize library to generate pdf's from the figures. Then I could share my tex sources with people that don't have, say python, nor the files that I used in the scripts.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find the solution?